# A question about a simple integral.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

How could I show that the $$\iint\sin(x)dxdy$$ along the domain $$x^2+y^2\leq1$$
is zero? I tried using polar coordinates but to no avail.
Had thought about claiming Sine is an odd function so the area is zero but could not really establish that.
As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try substitute $x=-u, y=v$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Had thought about claiming Sine is an odd function

Yes, that's the easiest way. The domain $D = \{(x,y) : x^2+y^2 \leqslant 1\}$ is symmetric, $$(x,y) \in D \iff (-x,y) \in D,$$ so for every fixed $y \in [-1,1]$, we have an inner integral

$$\int_{-a(y)}^{a(y)} \sin x\,dx = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Under the transformation $u = -x$, $v = -y$, the Jacobian is $1$, and because the region of integration $R$ remains unchanged under this transformation, we immediately obtain $$I = \int\!\!\!\int_R \sin(-u) \, du \, dv.$$  It then follows that $2I = 0$, or $I = 0$.  This is the "odd function" argument you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your last thought is the way.
$$
\iint_{x^2+y^2\le1}\sin x\,dxdy=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\sin x\,dx.
$$
Since $\sin x$ is odd, the inner integral is $0$.